# Why do we choose outer covers of the form [a,b) to find Lebesgue outer measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

My measure theory syllabus is based on the text **Measure Theory and Integration** by G de Barra, which specifies the choice of half open intervals  to find the Lebesgue outer measure of a set.
In order to find the **Lebesgue outer measure** of a set,why do we specifically choose intervals of the form, **[a,b)**? 
What changes can occur of we choose an open interval or a closed interval?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I don't. Any type of bounded interval will do.

Comment: the outer measure is the same for any chosen interval, say closed, open or half-closed

Comment: Also, some books use intervals of the form $[a,b]$ (e.g. "Measure and Integral" by Wheeden/Zygmund), some books use bounded intervals involving all 4 types regarding endpoint inclusion-exclusion (e.g. "Real Analysis" by Carothers), and some books use coverings by all bounded or unbounded intervals (e.g. "Measure and Category" by Oxtoby). One way to show these all generate the same set-function from $\mathcal P (\mathbb R)$ to $[0,\infty]$ is to prove each gives a $G_{\delta}$ regular outer measure that assigns to any interval its length and use the fact that any interval is a $G_{\delta}$ set.